# Install cuda java on mac 10.9

Tags: java, macos, cuda, homebrew

I am trying to install the GNU scientific library using homebrew on OSX (version 10.9.5) following [this link](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Build-Environments):

```
$ brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
$ brew cask install cuda java
$ brew install clang-omp swig bazel cmake libusb maven nasm yasm xz pkg-config
```

When I type `brew cask install cuda java` I get the following error message:

```
Error: Cask 'cuda' definition is invalid: Bad header line: parse failed
```

What does this mean, and how do I resolve this? If there is another way to get GSL on Java that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

That formula doesn't seem to exist.

You can look on https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/tree/master/Casks yourself to see a list of formula offered. There is a cuda and cuda-z formula shown, but no cuda java.

If you want to make absolutely sure you are not missing something, try:

```
brew search cuda java
```